# View: taxonomy_term, additional display of type page

Tags: views, 6, taxonomy-terms

I have two main content types with different vocabularies for tagging them.

I have enabled default Drupal view, "taxonomy_term".

I need two different displays: unformatted for content type A and table for content type B.

Content type A works ok, because it is using the default page display of this view.

I created another page display in this view with a filter to the proper vocabulary and node type.

Path is the same: taxonomy/term/%

But I am getting "Page not found" for taxonomy terms for content type B.

Could somebody help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can only have one page display on a particular path.

If you want to display two views on one url there are a number of ways you can do it.

Have one display page as you have, then have the second view as an attached view.

Or

Display the second view as a block and use context to display it on the same url